# How to create an x-www-form-urlencoded with an email that contains numbers?

Tags: angular

This is my web service's input

```
const data = new HttpParams()
            .set('email', output);
```

when I set an email address that contains numbers like **sana+30@gmail.com**

the request becomes **sana @gmail.com**

How can I override this condition?

Comment: Can you `console.log` the output value? Replacing your output variable with a literal string works fine for me. Also, for more help, create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: but I don't want to replace my output variable. I want that accept email that contains numbers

Comment: What I meant, was that by replacing it is working fine, which means that the error is somewhere else, not in the code you showed us. More information is needed for us to help you. Again, if you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it will help us to understand what the problem is.